# Vertical centered website with shadow

Tags: html, css

I asked yesterday about a website with shadow, but now I made a better example and want to ask again.

I need:

- Vertical centered website;
- Shadow on content block with variable height;
- A horizontal scrollbar must appear only when the browser window is smaller than content block (not the shadow block);
- Everything must stay aligned with a body background.

Now it looks fine, except for the moving `<div>`'s when you make the browser window smaller. It's probably caused by different `<div>` widths.

Can it be fixed?

http://www.uniground.net/test/

http://jsfiddle.net/NaSwF/17/

Comment: What about the background? On the sides, the background ends.. Do you wish to put some horizontally repeating patterns there?

Comment: No, my original background is wide enough.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the css-markup of `#content` with:

```
#content{
    width:656px;
    margin:0px 22px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Now, the white parts (the content div and its top and bottom divs) won't shift.

You might find  the distance between the conent div border and the text (the padding) too small (i.e. zero pixels); To address that, I suggest not using the padding property, but placing the text in yet another div inside the content div, with a certain margin instead.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not help much... (

Answer (score 1):

**NOTES**

- `#global_wrapper {}` has `max-width:;`, because your image is 1000px wide
- As you can see, I like to use .setwidth {} method for such layouts. However, in this case, I added `min-width:;` to `#global_wrapper` as well.
- Its a tricky layout and there are better ways of handling this. But that would bean re-cutting it.
- I also made some examples, where you ca use `margin-top:;` etc methods, to position something. In generally, you can do it only, when the outer containers dimensions are static. Meaning `#global_wrapper {margin-left: 50px;}` to set something to center -- is very very wrong (since body is dimensions are not static, but dynamic.)
- I added `<h1>` tag to `.contentbox_top`, so you can put the current pages title on top of the content
- Technically, the contentbox assembly is made pretty flexible, so you can use it more then once on your page.
- Since I redid your full code. I also added the menu_current and :hover feature. You can fully edit them from css.
- Added a `#logo`, as an example on where you can use `margin-top:;`
- You will run into problems with `#footer {position: absolute; bottom: 0px;}` so I gave you an alternative method with `#global_wrapper {height: 96px;}`
- The contentbox areas shadow cannot be hide, because you cut the hole thing wrong. And yes with more better boxing it could be achieved, you will still have top and bottom shadows.. That will look weird. So currently the layout works 100% with the shadows visible always. NOTE: All today's resolutions are bigger then 700px on with anyways ;)
- I hope you understand, that I recreated your full code from ground up.....

**Live demo: http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6993792.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vertical centered website with shadow - Kalle H. Väravas answer</title>
    <base href="http://www.uniground.net/test/" />
    <style>
        html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
        html, body, div, th, td, span, a {font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;}
        body {background: #C7C7C7 url('head_bg.png') top repeat-x;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4 {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
        .setwidth,
        .setwidth_2 {margin: 0px auto; color: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit;}
        .setwidth {width: 700px;}
        .setwidth_2 {width: 656px;}
        .tal {text-align: left;}
        .tac {text-align: center;}
        .tar {text-align: right;}
        #global_wrapper {background: url('main_background.jpg') center top no-repeat; height: 96%; margin: 0px auto; max-width: 1000px; min-width: 702px;}
            #top_level {background: url('head_bg.png') top repeat-x; height: 179px;}
                #logo {font-size: 30px; margin-top: 20px; display: inline-block; padding: 3px; background: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;}            
                #main_menu {margin-top: 20px;}
                    #main_menu ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
                        #main_menu ul li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline-block; background: #000000; margin-right: 10px;}
                            #main_menu ul li a {padding: 5px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; text-transform: uppercase;}
                            #main_menu ul li:hover {background: #FF93FF;}
                                #main_menu ul li:hover a {color: #FFFFFF;}
                            #main_menu ul li.menu_current {background: #FF00FF;}    
                                #main_menu ul li.menu_current a {color: #FFFFFF;}
            #content_area {}
                .contentbox_top,
                .contentbox_center_wrapper,
                .contentbox_bottom {margin: 0px auto; width: 700px;}
                .contentbox_top {background: url('content_top.jpg') center no-repeat; height: 52px;}
                    .contentbox_top h1 {font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; float: right; margin-right: 50px; margin-top: 25px;}
                .contentbox_center_wrapper {background: url('content_shadow.png') center repeat-y;}
                    .contentbox_center {background: #FFFFFF; width: 636px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 10px;}
                .contentbox_bottom {background: url('content_bottom.png') center no-repeat; height: 44px;}
        #footer {background: #333333; color: #C0C0C0; padding: 10px 0px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global_wrapper">
        <div id="top_level">
            <div class="setwidth_2">
                <div id="logo">Das Ist Meine Logo Hier</div>
                <div id="main_menu">
                    <ul><li class="menu_current"><a href="">Home</a></li><li><a href="">Production</a></li><li><a href="">Contact</a></li><li><a href="">About</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content_area">
            <div class="setwidth">
                <div class="contentbox_top"><h1>Home</h1></div>
                <div class="contentbox_center_wrapper">
                    <div class="contentbox_center">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentbox_bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="setwidth_2 tar">
            &copy; 2001
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, it's nice, but the shadow div is now forcing a horizontal scroll bar to appear (

Comment: As I explained in the notes. Nobodys resolution is that small. Everything else is static and works well. Why hide the shadows? It will leave the shadows on top and bottom anyways. This will not look good. You have many issues with that layout. This is not the best way of doing things, that's why everything is connected..if the shadow will be not static, then you will have alignment problems. You need to recut the full design then.

Comment: Ok, this is just a small example what i have posted above. Original dimensions are 950px content and 1080px shadow div. That's why i have to hide shadows on 1024px...

Comment: As I once said. Don't make examples for specific layouting problems, meaning don't scale them down. Because you need specific solutions not ideas.. Hmm, the problem is with the shadow container. I will think about this over the night. But do you want me to use the scaled example or maybe you want to post the real thing?

Comment: Kalle, i didn't scale it down, i've just did this example to specify the problem. The original page is much complex. I don't think, anybody wants to look through all the css and html. I will be grateful, if you'll find a solution for this example. I'm sure, I will be able to use it on original page.

Comment: Btw, it's not a problem to recut everything. How would you do it?

Comment: Come to chat. I can help you maybe.

Comment: @Sobakinet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2294/discussion-between-kalle-h-varavas-and-sobakinet)

Comment: I think i've got it... it works in modern browsers, but I think it may wark also in ie6 with some little tweaks http://www.uniground.net/test/dan2/